# Problem involving the product of a secant and its exterior section that is created through a perpendicular to an extended diameter.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The question:  The diameter AB of a circle is extended past B, and at a point
C on this extension CD perpendicular to AB is erected. If an arbitrary point M of this perpendicular is connected with A, and the other intersection
point of AM with the circle is denoted A', then AM times AA' is a fixed
quantity, i.e. it does not depend on the choice of M.

!http://www.hicksvillepublicschools.org/cms/lib2/NY01001760/Centricity/Domain/1129/KISELEV409.bmp

At first, I thought about dropping a perpendicular from A' to AC, labeling the point of intersection E.  Then, trying to show that triangle A'AE is similar to triangle MAC.  But after I did that, I noted, one that I didn't get anything that could be considered a fixed value (such as the radius or diameter of the circle) and, two that the proportions involving AM and AA' were not aligned so that I could get an expression for the product of AM and AA'.

Next, I considered drawing a tangent from M to the circle at the point F, then, using the secant-tangent theorem to get that (MF)^2 = AM times A'M.  But, that didn't get me anything in terms of AA' and, once again, there were no constants involved (as the length of MF varies depending upon where M is chosen on CD).

So, what other auxiliary lines / circles must I construct in order to proceed?  Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to word it, because the question itself was too long to post the entire thing; I edited it in hopes that it is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The triangles $AA'B$ and $ACM$  are similar.

Comment: Of course!!  Because angle AA'B is a right angle because it intercepts the arc created by the diameter (and thus AA'B is congruent to ACM), and angle A'AB is congruent to angle CAM by reflexivity.  I always miss the simple things.  Thank you!

Comment: @analysischallenged FYI. Besides saying thankyou, you can tick that post as an accepted answer. Otherwise, it is possible that your question will be listed “un-answered”.

Comment: It suffices to say that two right triangles with a common acute angle are similar.